# PostgreSQL Parametric Window Size

Tags: sql, postgresql, language-features

Does anyone know if SQL Standards define and PostgreSQL will implement (10.x or higher) **Parametric Window Size**?

Bellow a MVE of what I call a parametric window size:

```
WITH

D AS (SELECT T.x::FLOAT FROM generate_series(0., 10., 0.1) AS T(x)),
W AS (SELECT 10 AS WindowSize)

SELECT
    D.x
   ,AVG(D.x) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN W.WindowSize PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM
    D, W;
```

Which raises the following error:

```
ERROR:  argument of ROWS must not contain variables
LINE 8:    ,AVG(D.x) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN W.WindowSize PRECEDING AND C...
                                        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: argument of ROWS must not contain variables
SQL State: 42P10
```

I understand parametric window is kind of complex to implement. 
And I know that I can bypass some aspects of this limitation using Dynamic Query and PL/PGSQL.

My questions are:

- Do SQL Standards define such a thing?
- Will PostgreSQL implement it (if so, when is it planned)?
- If not, what are limitations to overcome before having such a feature?

Comment: It can't be that hard to implement -- at least for `ROWS`.  It is pretty easy to get the functionality in other ways, but that is not your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not standard SQL.

You can check this in the BNF:

http://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2008-foundation-grammar.html#window-frame-preceding

```
<window frame preceding> ::=
  <unsigned value specification> PRECEDING
```

`<unsigned value specification>` does not allow expressions. Bind parameters are allowed, btw.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, is it an official reference? Does it cover the complete SQL definition?

Comment: No, this is not official. But I've checked the 2016 relase – no obvious difference. The linked BNF claims to cover part 2 of the ISO standard. See here what the different parts are: http://modern-sql.com/standard/parts